# alternative for deployment class in non-silverlight application

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any other way to use Deployment class or another class which serves the same purpose as deployment class in Silverlight application.
I am implementing a non-silverlight application(Mobile App) where in I have written a line like this:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => lblTranslatedText.Text = strTest);
```

then it is showing me like :

**the name Deployment does not exist in current context**

I tried every possibility like `System.Windows.Deployment` as it is non-silverlight application I am unable to use deployment class. suggest me a solution please.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Runtime apps you'll use the Windows.UI.Core.[CoreDispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.aspx) object's [RunAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx) method. You can get usually get this from app's current Window:

```
await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(...);
```

Or

```
await CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.RunAsync(...);
```

Comment: I have tried both of them it is showing me something like this 

using Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher does not contain a definition for BeingInvoke nad no extension method accepting BeingInvoke and accepting a first argument of type using Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher could be found(are u missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

i have written an assembly directive like using WIndows.UI.Core;

Comment: d'oh. Sorry about that. RunAsync is the analogous method to BeginInvoke.